# Combining "Success Message" and the next step on the same screen

Tags: user-expectation, notification, messages

How normal is it to combine 'success messages' with the next step in the process...? For example below:

**First screen** will ask for payment but in our flow, payment isn't the last step. However, it looks a bit off to have a success message (for payment) while the process hasn't ended yet (**Second screen**)...

**FIRST SCREEN:**

[image]

**SECOND SCREEN:**

[image]

What is a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Within your process there seems to be several sections (as far as i understood one is payment another is survey). Also the process is not completed until the last step is reached.

"it looks a bit off to have a success message (for payment) while the process hasn't ended yet". You can **make the user aware of all the steps in the process, the different sections of it and that the process won't be valid until the last step is reached** and confirmed.

You could make use of [Steppers](https://material.google.com/components/steppers.html#). Make the process clear with all the steps and different sections there are, in every screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The success message does look a little final.
I think you might want to look at something like this (I can't really find a name for it).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGdA1r.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(Think of the cart as a delivery van, balsamiq didn't have the right icon)

This would communicate a success message while also indicating more steps are following.

Comment: I call it progress indicators :)